# VirtualBox: USB drive recognized but not listed

Tags: debian, virtualbox, usb-drive

I'm running Debian on a VirtualBox machine (Windows 7 is the host o.s.). I attached a USB drive and selected into the guest system.

I can see it's recognized in `dmesg` output:

```
[  785.492007] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  785.828824] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0723, bcdDevice=94.54
[  785.828828] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[  785.828829] usb 1-1: Product: USB Storage
[  785.828831] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic 
[  785.832894] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  785.833069] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  786.846942] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9454 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  786.848136] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  786.866936] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

but it's not listed in `fdisk -l` output, nor in `lsusb` or `lspci`. But `/dev/sdb` exists.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

My bet on what is happening is that the drive is mounting into the host OS, in your 
case Windows 7. These links may help.

[Link 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/mounting-usb-drive-that-is-not-recognized?rq=1)

[Link 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68861/external-drive-not-being-recognized?rq=1)

[Link 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197201/mount-external-hard-drive-automatically?rq=1)